# Magento: How to display how many times a product has been sold?

Tags: magento

I want to echo on my homepage the total sales of a product. How can this be done?

Also i would like to know how to query Total items sold (quantity) on the front page.

In my shop, there will be only 1 product (virtual).

**Edit**:

I found this code and it works pretty well in the product's view page.

```
$sku = nl2br($_product->getSku());
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->getFirstItem();
$product = $_productCollection;

echo 'Already Bought '.(int)$product->ordered_qty;
```

But on the front page, how would I point directly to the ID of the product i want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$id = 123; // enter your product ID here
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('id', $id)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->getFirstItem();

echo 'Already Bought '.(int)$product->ordered_qty;
```

Comment: thank you vzwick, unfortunatelly when i paste this code in a .phtml page that will load in frontpage, the page will not stop loading. (at the point that is suppose to echo the quantity sold by my product. Do you have any ideas ? i do it with <?php and close ?> tags

Comment: ok, i did it with$sku instead of id, and now it's pulling the correct sales of the product :)

Comment: how can I add a filter saying, that I want all sold items since yesterday

Comment: @Safari - you should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
//This will show  total sales of all the products 
<?php    
     foreach(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() as $product)
     {
            $productId= $product->getId();
            $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $name = $productModel->load($productId)->getName();
            echo "<br/>";
            $product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $productId))
                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                ->getFirstItem();
            echo (int)$product->ordered_qty.'&nbsp'.$name.' Have Been Sold';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be next:

```
$id = $_product->getId();
    $product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $id))
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->getFirstItem();
    echo 'Downloaded '.(int)$product->ordered_qty.'times';
```

this code nice work as for me(display how many times, **curent product** has been sold)

Answer (score 0):

Display product by max sold product on listing page

```
$i=0;  
foreach($_collection as $product)  
     {  
            $productId= $product->getId();  
            $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
            $name = $productModel->load($productId)->getName();  
            $product1 = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')  
                ->addOrderedQty()  
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' =>     $productId))  
                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')  
                ->getFirstItem();  
            $solditems[$i]= array($product1->ordered_qty,$product);  
            $i++;  
        }    
            rsort($solditems);  
print_r($solditems);
```