# Get total revenue generated by a product in magento

Tags: magento

How can I programmatically get the total revenue generated by a product in Magento?

Suppose there is a product with `id` as `1` and it's sold at $10, five times and at $5 (discounted rate), eight times so i want to get a total of $90 from Magento. Is this possible??

Comment: Hi, this is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Magento's community support resources may be the better place for this.

Comment: Have you looked at the database schema?

Comment: Pekka this is a programming question, actually I want to display the value in the front end.

Comment: Yes, this is a programming question involving Magento domain logic. It's a good example of why there is a [proposal at Area51 for a Magento-dedicated site (link)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento?referrer=HFqQT3Qeb2X27y6ehRWkiw2)

Comment: Is this about tier prices?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer posted here for the basis of my code suggestion

[Magento: How to display how many times a product has been sold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808213/magento-how-to-display-how-many-times-a-product-has-been-sold)

Since you are wanting to display this value in the frontend, i'm assuming phtml, so I'll code it that way, and just attempt to multiply final price by qty sold.

```
<?php
        // Enter your product ID here 
        $id = 123; 

        // Load the product collection and do some filters   
        $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('id', $id)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
            ->getFirstItem();

        // Since the filter selects one product, we can use it here as the single result
        $product = $_productCollection;

        // Load the tax helper
        $_taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');

        // Get the final price of the product
        $finalprice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true);


        // Print the results
        echo $product->getName() . " total revenue: " . (int)$product->ordered_qty * $finalprice;
?>
```

This is untested, coded on the fly, but the concepts are pretty basic so you should have no trouble adapting what I've shown to do what you need.