# Magento - How to get Revenue by Product

Tags: magento

I'm fighting with this on Magento.

I added to the Product Ordered report a few columns and i want to have one with the Total Revenue for that specific product.

Check this example: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e94d0yi29

The total revenue number is wrong, i did the review of each order and it's not that number.

What am i doing wrong? Here's the code:

**site>app>code>core>Mage>Adminhtml>Block>Report>Product>Sold**

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid
{
/**
 * Sub report size
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $_subReportSize = 0;

/**
 * Initialize Grid settings
 *
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('gridProductsSold');
}

protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $totalObj = new Mage_Reports_Model_Totals();
    $this->setTotals($totalObj->countTotals($this));
}

/**
 * Prepare collection object for grid
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()
            ->initReport('reports/product_sold_collection');

    return $this;
}


protected function _getStore()
{
    $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
    return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
}

/**
 * Prepare Grid columns
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('producer_tag');

    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
        $collection->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');
    }
    if ($store->getId()) {
        //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
        $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
        $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'name',
            'catalog_product/name',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $adminStore
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'custom_name',
            'catalog_product/name',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'status',
            'catalog_product/status',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'visibility',
            'catalog_product/visibility',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'price',
            'catalog_product/price',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'left',
            $store->getId()
        );
    }
    else {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    }


    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Name'),
        'index'     =>'order_items_name'
    ));

      $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
        ->load()
        ->toOptionHash();

    $this->addColumn('set_name',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Category'),
            'width' => '150px',
            'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => $sets,
    ));

    $this->addColumn('producer_tag',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Producer Tag'),
            'width' => '150px',
            'index' => 'producer_tag',
            'type'  => 'text'
    ));


    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $this->addColumn('price',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
            'type'  => 'price',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'index' => 'price',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Quantity Ordered'),
        'width'     =>'120px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'ordered_qty',
        'total'     =>'sum',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));

 $currencyCode = $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $rate = $this->getRate($currencyCode);
    $this->addColumn('revenue',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Revenue (Only Complete Orders)'),
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'index' => 'price',
            'total' => 'sum',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currencyCode,
            'rate'  => $rate,
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSoldCsv', Mage::helper('reports')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSoldExcel', Mage::helper('reports')->__('Excel XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
}
```

Don't get what i'm doing wrong here.

My goal is to have a report of how much money i did with each of those products.

Any help or ideal will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer posted here for the basis of my code suggestion

[Magento: How to display how many times a product has been sold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196250/get-total-revenue-generated-by-a-product-in-magento)

since you are wanting to display this value in the frontend, i'm assuming phtml, so I'll code it that way, and just attempt to multiply final price by qty sold.

```
<?php
        // Enter your product ID here 
        $id = 123; 

        // Load the product collection and do some filters   
        $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('id', $id)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
            ->getFirstItem();

        // Since the filter selects one product, we can use it here as the single result
        $product = $_productCollection;

        // Load the tax helper
        $_taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');

        // Get the final price of the product
        $finalprice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true);


        // Print the results
        echo $product->getName() . " total revenue: " . (int)$product->ordered_qty * $finalprice;
?>
```

This is untested, coded on the fly, but the concepts are pretty basic so you should have no trouble adapting what I've shown to do what you need.

Comment: Saw your answer in another thread but i was looking doing it on Product Ordered current report, but as i talked with other developers, it's not recommended.
I want a report of products with a range of dates, all products sold with details. But i'm checking this with a developer.
Thanks so much for your reponse!

Comment: This is pointless, what if final price changes which always will do for everyone.