# how to display the sold out percentage in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to display the sold out percentage of product in magento.

For a example I am having 10 watches of a brand, in that two are sold out,

In that I product I want to sold out percentage like 20% and the bar which is indicating the sold out percetage.

Please help me out.

Regards
MD.Samiuddin

Answer (score 0):

Hi Do you mean something like this?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $initialAmount = 10;
    $itemsLeft  = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                  ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
    $sold = $initialAmount - $itemsLeft;
    $perc = $sold/$initialAmount*100;
?>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .bar {
        height: 20px; 
        width:100%; 
        border: 1px solid #000000; 
        background-color: green;
    }

    .fill {
        height: 20px; 
        width: <?php echo $perc; ?>%; 
        background-color: #FF0000; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        text-align: right; 
        line-height: 20px; 
        vertical-align: middle;   
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='bar'>
    <div class="fill"> <?php echo $perc; ?>%</div>
</div>
```

**Check**
[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T2MEiQ)

Comment: Thank you very much I was looking for this. But the stock value should come dynamically.

Comment: Maybe this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808213/magento-how-to-display-how-many-times-a-product-has-been-sold